# Java Android Studio: Progressbars look old (like Android 5)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar

I recently encountered a strange problem. When I try to add progress bars to my project, their appearance looks like the stone-age of android apps:

[image]

They also look like this in the final build for Android 12. They are also really laggy. I'd like to use the default Material Design Progressbars. It seems to work for every other project I have, except for this.

This is the code I use for the Progressbars (just the code, Android Studio uses via the designer view):

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar5"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And this is the default-config of the build.gradle:

```
 defaultConfig {
    
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.1"
}
```

Comment: Are you using `android.widget.ProgressBar`?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Thank you for your comment. I added the code samples to the question - is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Use material components

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/ProgressIndicator.md

Comment: show your apps theme file

Comment: just use a custom library those look great... like this one https://github.com/ybq/Android-SpinKit or similar

Answer (score 0):

Try to change style

```
 <ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/Bar"
  style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:progress="25"/>
```